Need helping finding this web novel about a reincarnated girl who only wants to read
As the title says. It's rather obscure and I only remember a few details. MC is the reincarnation of one of the three siblings who were transmigrated into the fantasy world. She just wants to read and has a knack of burning servants who come and get her. One detail I remember is the MC remembers her world when she hears someone singing Claire de la lune.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  You say she was the reincarnation of a transmigrator?  She travelled to the fantasy world and then died and was reincarnated?  Or do you just mean she died in her original world and was reincarnated in the fantasy world?

Burning servants? Like literally causing them to catch fire?

Ascendance of a Bookworm fits a girl reincarnated in a fantasy world who wants to read, but she has no sisters in her original world and only one in the fantasy world.  Her family are also poor and have no servants.

I vaguely remember a scene like this in a manga. It was the comedic "ash face and clothes damage" kind of burning.
